# Testing method injected class against existing injector

Tags: java, unit-testing, guice

I have a set of classes that are injected at runtime, because of a legacy code base. I want to write a unit test that checks the injector can satisfy all injected dependencies of those classes. I already have the list of classes to be injected available, and I can instantiate the injector, in `Stage.TOOL`, because otherwise it will do stuff like connect to a database.

My question is, how do I check those classes against the injector? I've tried `injector.getMembersInjector(classToBeInjected)`, but this fails because injectors in `Stage.TOOL` do not support it. Basically, I don't need the injector instance, but I need it to check if it *could be* created.

For reference, here is my current implementation:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class HtmlActionInjectTest {
    @Parameters(name="{1}")
    public static List<Object[]> parameters() {
        return ImmutableList.of(classesUnderTest);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.TOOL, myLongListOfModules);
    }

    private static Injector injector;
    private final Class<?> actionClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        injector.getMembersInjector(actionClass);
    }
}
```

I've also tried using the SPI api, using `Elements.getElements(myModules)`, but I couldn't get it to tell me if the dependencies of the `classToBeInjected` can be satisfied.

Example of a class under test:

```
public class MyAction implements SomeInterface {
  public MyAction(UnInjectableDependency dep) {
    // can't be injected here for legacy reasons
  }

  @Inject void doInject(SomeDep dep) {
     this.dep = dep;
  }

  @Override void someInterfaceMethod() { /* you get the idea */ }
}
```

Comment: You should use `Stage.DEVELOPMENT` instead os `Stage.TOOL`. `Stage.TOOL` is intented for "We're running in a tool (an IDE plugin for example)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution with the help of a colleague.

Guice offers a class called `InjectionPoint`, which can be used to find all dependencies of the class to be injected. So, the solution looks like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class HtmlActionInjectTest {
    @Parameters(name="{1}")
    public static List<Object[]> parameters() {
        return ImmutableList.of(classesUnderTest);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        bindings = Guice.createInjector(Stage.TOOL, myLongListOfModules).getAllBindings().keySet();
    }

    private static Set<Key<?>> bindings;
    private final Class<?> actionClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        for (InjectionPoint point : InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(actionClass)) {
            for (Dependency<?> dependency : point.getDependencies()) {
                assertTrue("injector cannot satisfy dependency " + dependency.getKey() + " in " + actionClass.getName(), bindings.contains(dependency.getKey()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```